# minimum html to preview when linked to facebook

Tags: html, facebook

I'm creating a script to generate vanilla HTML5 given an existing media file on my server. What is the minimum HTML5 needed to ensure that Facebook will present nice looking previews to media wrapped by my script?

My HTML template is below; I'd like to add the minimum code to get the following should a link to be shared on Facebook:

1. a preview image (let's call it "wrapperlogo.png")
2. a title (let's suppose it's just the word "TITLE"), shown as the article title.

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   </head>
   <body>
     <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
       <source src="$url" type="audio/mpeg">
     </video>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "Open Graph Tags". Which ones is explained here: http://ogp.me/

Here´s more information about sharing from Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices?locale=es_ES

Last but not least, this is important for image resolutions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images